# Earliest Time in Datetime column PowerBI

Tags: datetime, powerbi

Okay so I have a table like shown...

[image]

I want to use PowerBI to create a new column called 'First_Interaction' where it will say 'True' if this was the user's earliest entry for that day. Any entry that came in after the first entry will be set to "False".

This is what I want the column to be like...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following DAX formula to create a column:

```
First_Interaction = 
VAR __userName = 'Table'[UserName]
VAR __minDate = CALCULATE( MIN( 'Table'[Datetime] ), FILTER( 'Table', 'Table'[UserName] = __userName ) )
Return IF( 'Table'[Datetime] = __minDate, "TRUE", "FALSE" )
```

Power BI dosnt support less than second so your DateTime Column must be a Text value. Take that on consideration for future transformation.